# Docker Compose + TypeORM: No Connection

Tags: postgresql, docker, typeorm

I know there are plenty of questions around this topic, but I can't make it work for my (fairly straightforward setup). What am I missing? I guess we can neglect pgadmin out of the equation, but I kept in there for full disclosure.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
      PGDATA: /data/mydatabase
    volumes:
      - pgstore:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.5
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-admin@admin.com}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - '5050:80'
    networks:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  pgstore:
  pgadmin:
```

Starting it with `docker-compose up` yields:

```
Creating network "my-app_postgres" with driver "bridge"
Creating my-app_postgres_1 ... done
Creating my-app_pgadmin_1  ... done
Attaching to my-app_postgres_1, my-app_pgadmin_1
postgres_1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres_1  | This user must also own the server process.
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres_1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres_1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /data/mydatabase ... ok
postgres_1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres_1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres_1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres_1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres_1  | selecting default time zone ... UTC
postgres_1  | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres_1  | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres_1  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... sh: locale: not found
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:48.965 UTC [32] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
postgres_1  | ok
postgres_1  | syncing data to disk ... initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres_1  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres_1  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres_1  | ok
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  |     pg_ctl -D /data/mydatabase -l logfile start
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | waiting for server to start....2022-09-06 14:03:49.890 UTC [38] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 on aarch64-unknown-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 10.3.1 20211027, 64-bit
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:49.891 UTC [38] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:49.894 UTC [39] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-06 14:03:49 UTC
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:49.896 UTC [38] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1  |  done
postgres_1  | server started
postgres_1  | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | waiting for server to shut down....2022-09-06 14:03:50.195 UTC [38] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.196 UTC [38] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.197 UTC [38] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 45) exited with exit code 1
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.197 UTC [40] LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.204 UTC [38] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_1  |  done
postgres_1  | server stopped
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.307 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 on aarch64-unknown-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 10.3.1 20211027, 64-bit
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.308 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.308 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.310 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.313 UTC [52] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-06 14:03:50 UTC
postgres_1  | 2022-09-06 14:03:50.315 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
pgadmin_1   | NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
pgadmin_1   |
pgadmin_1   | [2022-09-06 14:03:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
pgadmin_1   | [2022-09-06 14:03:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
pgadmin_1   | [2022-09-06 14:03:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
pgadmin_1   | [2022-09-06 14:03:56 +0000] [89] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 89
```

In my application, I initialize TypeORM with the following options:

```
const options = {
  default: {
    type: process.env.DATABASE_TYPE,
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
  },
};
```

Whereas my `.env` holds the following information:

```
DATABASE_TYPE=postgres
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
DATABASE_NAME=mydatabase
```

I can access the container on the command line with:

```
docker exec -it my-app psql -U postgres mydatabase
```

and list the `\l` the databases and see `mydatabase`. But I get `Did not find any relations.` for `\d` because the application does not connect to the database and therefore there are no relations yet.

More information:

- the application is running outside of the container
- the application is not throwing an error, it just tries to connect indefinitely
- I am using Docker container on MacOS

What am I missing here? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the application also running in a container, or outside a container on the same host?  Are you using Docker Desktop, or Docker directly on native Linux, or some other setup?  What error are you getting when you run the application?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I edited my question to have all this information.

Comment: Let's start with the basic troubleshooting steps; With the cotnainer up and running are you able to connect to it with any kind of SQL tool? What are the application logs you are seeing that signify there is no connection? You will need to share this information as well.

Comment: Thanks for asking @akortex I added it to my question. I can access the container on the command line and see the database there.

Somewhere else I read that `DATABASE_HOST=localhost` may be wrong. I read about using `db` or `postgres` here, but did not have any success.

Comment: Is the connection to the pg databse possible over pgadmin or does that fail too?

Comment: I can open pgadmin and access it with the credentials, but I don't see any database in there.